# My SQL query order so that no same value from the column come together

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I m fetching data from multiple tables and want to sort the result so that no two values come together.

for example query returns the following data.

23

25

26

26

22

22

19

I want this result to be ordered like this so that no two values come consuctivley.

23

25

26

22

26

22

19

Comment: If you are doing JOIN then `order by` should do the trick, and if you are doing UNION ALL then do an outer select of data and then do order by `select col1,col2.. from ( select col1,col2 from tab1 UNION ALL select col1,col2 from tab2)t order by col1`

Comment: Without some formula to apply which would generate this type of ordering, I don't see how one could do this.  You're wanting to apply an ordering type that doesn't exist within mySQL (asc, dec)  it appears you want random no duplicate consecutive.  and again a formula would have to be applied to this.  It is possible just painful...

Answer (score 1):

You actually cannot guarantee that no two values come together (for instance, all values might be the same).  But you can distribute them.  Here is a method using a subquery and variables:

```
select t.*
from (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@v = col, @rn + 1,
                        if(@v := col, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (query) q cross join
           (select @v := -1, @rn := 0) vars
      order by col
     ) t
order by rn, col;
```

Comment: But how can I achieve this if my result is coming from multiple tables.

Comment: Here is my query
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS T1.* , T7.First_name FROM `fl_listings` AS `T1` LEFT JOIN `fl_listing_plans` AS `T2` ON `T1`.`Plan_ID` = `T2`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `fl_listing_plans` AS `T4` ON `T1`.`Featured_ID` = `T4`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `fl_categories` AS `T3` ON `T1`.`Category_ID` = `T3`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `fl_accounts` AS `T7` ON `T1`.`Account_ID` = `T7`.`ID` LEFT JOIN `fl_listings_book` AS `BT1` ON `T1`.`ID` = `BT1`.`Listing_ID` WHERE `T1`.Date >= '2014-05-30'  AND `T3`.`Type` = 'listings' ORDER BY `T1`.`listing_enhaned` ASC , `T1`.`Date` DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: @mohsin139 . . . Put your query where `query` is.